# Elements 12 upgrading to Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, photoshop-elements, import

I have 2000+ images on an IMAC/Elements 12. I am thinking about buying LR. As I install LR will it automatically recognise my existing folders and libraries? Or is there a link that explains this?

Comment: This question may belong in [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom can import/convert an Elements catalog into a Lightroom catalog (both are just SQLite databases). The import process will retain your edits, star ratings, keyword tags, etc. [Adobe has a webpage explaining the process](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/how-to/elements-upgrade-creative-cloud-photography.html). The basic steps are:

1. Install Lightroom.
2. Open Lightroom.
3. Select the menu command **File > Import a Photoshop Elements Catalog**.
4. Navigate to the Elements catalog file you want to use.
5. Click **Import**.

Comment: Thank You, hope it works ok, I've seen some people have had issues and have had to repair the database but thanks again I'm going to buy LR

Comment: @K4ROJ. You're welcome. Because this is SE, and not a messageboard, consider [accepting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), or (when you get the rep) [upvoting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer instead of a thanks comment. Please, take [the tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) if you plan to stick around.